# Only getting two of three transaction events

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to log the events of a contract on block 12735294, with the following code:

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract([], '0x3B3ee1931Dc30C1957379FAc9aba94D1C48a5405');
    
contract.getPastEvents('allEvents', { fromBlock: 12735294, toBlock: 12735294 }, function (error, events) { console.log(events); })
```

On Etherscan three events are shown for the transaction I find: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x692ef7e7e923decfd6ace30062a840c7faa1df0798b31a3dcb4b1c48eb35f8b3#eventlog

However, I only seem to be logging two of them:

```
events [
  {
    address: '0x3B3ee1931Dc30C1957379FAc9aba94D1C48a5405',
    blockNumber: 12735294,
    transactionHash: '0x692ef7e7e923decfd6ace30062a840c7faa1df0798b31a3dcb4b1c48eb35f8b3',
    transactionIndex: 130,
    blockHash: '0x933b68b81eec5de42bfada91b9a8a8a35f507500f4d17e06fc0a062ddee70da5',      
    logIndex: 334,
    removed: false,
    id: 'log_c798ad20',
    returnValues: Result {},
    event: undefined,
    signature: null,
    raw: { data: '0x', topics: [Array] }
  },
  {
    address: '0x3B3ee1931Dc30C1957379FAc9aba94D1C48a5405',
    blockNumber: 12735294,
    transactionHash: '0x692ef7e7e923decfd6ace30062a840c7faa1df0798b31a3dcb4b1c48eb35f8b3',
    transactionIndex: 130,
    blockHash: '0x933b68b81eec5de42bfada91b9a8a8a35f507500f4d17e06fc0a062ddee70da5',
    logIndex: 335,
    removed: false,
    id: 'log_32f96506',
    returnValues: Result {},
    event: undefined,
    signature: null,
    raw: { data: '0x', topics: [Array] }
  }
]
```

Why am I not getting the third transaction?

Comment: A super interesting question -t his should not be the case. Is your node fully synced to the chain?

Comment: That is a good question @MikkoOhtamaa, it might not be because it's a fairly recent transaction, and I'm using a managed blockchain service. I'll give this some time, and check again.

Comment: On normal nodes, you can use `syncing` API to check what the node thinks is the latest block it knows (information might be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api is showing events from the contract `0x3B3ee1931Dc30C1957379FAc9aba94D1C48a5405`.

In the Etherscan page there're two events from that contract the third event is from `0xcda72070e455bb31c7690a170224ce43623d0b6f`.

To obtain the three events you can to retrieve the receipt from the transaction. Web3 does not decode the "internal transactions", but with the raw data and the it should be possible to decode them.

Comment: Looks like you are right. I'm essentially trying to get all transactions for this token: https://etherscan.io/token/0x3b3ee1931dc30c1957379fac9aba94d1c48a5405

How do I make sure that I find all the contracts for this token? So that I can see every token transaction.

Comment: @committer That contract is a proxy, the token code is here [FNDNFT721](https://etherscan.io/address/0xab717127a407065290e49cd004b90eb83069e7b3#code).